# While scanning for badchars to avoid in a buffer overflow attack, hex number "C2" keeps appearing every second character in the hexdump

Tags: python, buffer-overflow, penetration-testing

I'm learning about buffer overflows because I have an exam on it tomorrow.
I've been following [this guide](https://www.hackingarticles.in/a-beginners-guide-to-buffer-overflow/), and I'm currently on the step where I'm using [immunity debugger](https://www.immunityinc.com/products/debugger/) to look for badchars. However, a weird problem is occurring where after I get to the hex number "7F", where for some reason every second number appears to be "C2".

[image: as you can see, after it gets to 7F, shit gets weird...]

I'm using a script which is slightly modified from the guide since I'm using python3 instead of python2. That script looks like this:

```
import socket

ip = "192.168.10.136"
port = 31337
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ip, port))

offset = 146
eip = "B" * 4
allchars = "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x3b\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f\x40\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4e\x4f\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x5b\x5c\x5d\x5e\x5f\x60\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b\x7c\x7d\x7e\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff"
buffer = "A" * offset + eip + allchars
buffer += "\n"
s.sendall(buffer.encode('utf-8'))
```

I couldn't find anything online, it was a kind of hard problem to troubleshoot, especially since I'm not super experienced with python3 or immunity debugger. Any help is very appreciated, and I'll do my best to answer any questions if there's any important information I've forgotten to include.

Comment: You data shows the entire ascii character set in sequence followed by what looks like binary garbage. Have you any reason to suppose that the buffer you are examining contains valid data after the `}` (ascii 126) character?

Comment: That's not binary garbage. That's utf-8 encoded data. Just like OP requested in their last line of code.

Comment: @BoarGules according to the guide, I'm supposed to use the mona.py module to find the JMP ESP address, and I need to know all the badchars, so I can specify that the mona.py script shouldn't return any memory pointer with badchars in it. Additionally, later I will use it to generate badchar-free shellcode. I don't know if it's reasonable to assume there's going to be any need for characters outside the ascii range, but I'm trying to follow the guide as closely as possible. As I mentioned earlier, I'm quite inexperienced, and want to find out what I'm doing wrong so I can avoid it in the future

Comment: As @Sören points out, you have encoded your original data as UTF-8. Your original data goes from byte value `01` to `FF` which, because it is in a string, represents the Unicode codepoints  `U+0001` to `U+00FF`. But Unicode codepoints `U+0080` to `U+00FF` are represented in UTF-8 as two bytes. So when you encoded the original data `0x80` `0x81` etc  as UTF-8 you got the UTF-8 2-byte representations `C2 80` `C2 81` etc. The first 32 of those are undefined control characters so I stand by *binary garbage*. To fix: Make `allchars` a bytestring `b"..."` and use it as is without encoding.

Comment: @BoarGules Thank you very much. That worked. I thought UTF-8 was represented by 1 byte, but evidently I was wrong. If you want to post that as an answer, I can press the checkmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Comment promoted to answer at OP's request.*

As @Sören points out, you have encoded your original data as UTF-8. Your original data goes from byte value `01` to `FF` which, because it is in a string, represents the Unicode codepoints `U+0001` to `U+00FF`.

But the values in the second half of that block, Unicode codepoints `U+0080` to `U+00FF`, are represented in UTF-8 as two bytes. So when you encoded the original data `0x80` `0x81` etc as UTF-8 you got the UTF-8 2-byte representations `C2 80` `C2 81` etc.

To fix: Make `allchars` a bytestring `b"..."` and use it as is without encoding.

Unicode is a 21-bit system that can accommodate a theoretical 1,114,112 different codepoints (though only 144,697 of them were assigned as of Unicode 14.0, in 2021). UTF-8 does represent some codepoints as a single byte: essentially, the 127 characters of the ASCII character set from 1963. But it follows from number of codepoints that any representation in 8-bit units will be variable width, with some codepoints occupying two, three or even four bytes.